# accessing ruby object attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am using oauth to create an oauth object which looks like this -

```
>> y @oauth
--- !ruby/object:LinkedIn::Oauth 
api_key: ggrgergrgrgrg
api_secret: 
consumer: &id001 !ruby/object:OAuth::Consumer 
key: ggergergrgrg
options: 
   blah blah
```

I can access

@oauth.consumer but not @oauth.api_key

Any ideas ?

Thanks, Alex

Comment: what do you mean by can't access, is there a `NoMethodError`?

Comment: maybe the reader method doesn't exists on LinkedIn::Oauth, check the code of this class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a private method? Try accessing it with `@oauth.send(:api_key)`

Comment: Thanks for your responses! it was a private method. Does anyone have a good resource for learning about ruby objects ?

Comment: There's a great book called "Metaprogramming Ruby: Program Like the Ruby Pros" that I recently read. It discusses this exact topic. A little advanced, but if you're interested, definitely worth a read.